# Show in Taskbar=false behavior

Tags: wpf, vsix

Hi I have one VSIX project. I have added a WPF form to that project for UI .
and set show in taskbar=false for that wpf window.While executing the project, it has been shown in the main window of experimental instance no issues with that. But when i switch over to another window and return back to the Experimental instance window  the wpf window get disappeared.How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issue has been fixed by the below snippet.

```
Form = new MainWindow();
  Form.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
 Form.ShowDialog();
```